# Sql Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) For mySql Not Showing All Tables

Tags: sql-server-migration-assi

I'm using SSMA version 6.0 for mySql. After I connect to the mySQL source database, it's only showing 45 of the 300+ tables in the schema I want to migrate.   I don't see any properties or settings to limit the number of tables displayed. I did change "Data Migration Timeout" setting that someone else suggested.  But, it didn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're sure the login you're using has all the privileges it needs?

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in your Project Settings as follows.

```
General - Migration - Batch Size = 99999999 (Maximum value)
GUI - Maximum Row Number of Source = 999999999 (Maximum value)
Maximum Row Number of Target = 999999999 (Maximum value)
```

Happy Querying :) .