# MySql to SQL Server - SQL Server Migration Assistance tool is showing few tables

Tags: sql-server, database, database-migration, sql-server-2014, sql-server-migration-assi

We have a database which has 511 tables and 'SQL Server Migration Assistance for MySQL' is showing only 31 tables. I am using Version-6.0.0. It is not showing any error in 'output' window.

Followed - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXe4XL41jVE for migration.

I have a table which has 87120301 records, and this is the last table which is displayed. Is there any restrictions for this tool ?.

Is there any other tool I can use for this **Big Data Migration**?.
Total size of the database in MySQL is 37GB.

Comment: Are you certain your user account has access to all tables? Are you certain these are tables (not views or synonyms?)

Comment: Yes. I am the administrator. These are tables. Used this query to verify SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'dbname'; and it says 511.

Comment: You could try this to confirm whether or not they are views: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834016/how-to-get-a-list-of-mysql-views

Comment: Confirmed, all are tables.

Comment: Well that rules those two things out. Looks like you aren't the only one with this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467853/sql-server-migration-assistant-ssma-for-mysql-not-showing-all-tables. This suggests extending the timeout but I doubt it will help: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29688/error-migrating-a-big-table-from-mysql-to-sql-server-2012

Comment: Looking into second link. I will update you soon. Thanks

Comment: No still not working its showing only 31 table. I have changed two setting in Project Settings. General -> Migration -> Batch Size = 99999999 which is the maximum value. GUI -> Maximum Row Number of Source = 999999999 I have also changed Maximum Row Number of Target = 999999999. Please help.

Comment: It started working. I had to refresh and wait till those table load. Thanks @Nick.McDermaid. Its working, At the least it is showing all the tables.

Comment: Are you saying after you pressed refresh somewhere and waited, the tables appeared? If you're pretty sur eyou know what you did it would be of great value for you to document it and accept it as an answer as this seems to be a common problem for many people without an actual answer online. You might get a SO badge for it!!

Comment: Yes. After changing the settings we have to refresh the mysql database. Then the output window it shows the information what it is fetching. It took couple of minutes and it is now showing all the tables. But its taking time to change the schema, which is fine because its a large database and it has many tables. Wondering how much it is going to take to migrate :) ..

Comment: A migration project is always long and painful... if you have a tool that helps that's a good thing even if you have to wait around a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made changes in Project Settings as follows.

```
General - Migration - Batch Size = 99999999 (Maximum value)
GUI - Maximum Row Number of Source = 999999999 (Maximum value)
Maximum Row Number of Target = 999999999 (Maximum value)
```

Its working now.